# The FileReader cannot find my text file

Tags: java, filereader, java-io

I have a simple text file and for some reason, it cannot be found. I don't see anything wrong with the code because I got it from a site, and I am starting to think that I didn't place the text file in the right place. Any suggestion please?

### Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class MainFavorites {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        /**
        * finds pathway to the file
        */
        //      File file = new File("icecreamTopping.txt");
        //      System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        ArrayList <String> myFileLines = new ArrayList <String>();
        try {
            String sCurrentLine;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("icecreamTopping.txt"));
            while ((sCurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                myFileLines.add(sCurrentLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null)reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        int numElements = myFileLines.size();
        System.out.println ("there are n lines in the file:" + numElements);

        for (int counter = numElements-1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
            String mylineout = myFileLines.get(counter);
            System.out.println (mylineout);
        }
    }
}
```

### File content:

```
1- Blueberry 
2- Banana Buzz
3- Cookie Batter
```

My stack trace is this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\homar_000\workspace\RankFavorites\icecreamTopping.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at MainFavorites.main(MainFavorites.java:28)
```

Comment: "for some reason, it cannot be found." which means what? Paste the stacktrace

Comment: Oh, and you don't specify the charset to use for reading the file

Comment: Maybe some people are just beginners, EJP? lol
Anyways, my stack trace is this:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\homar_000\workspace\RankFavorites\icecreamTopping.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at MainFavorites.main(MainFavorites.java:28)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out what was the problem. It was unnecessary for me to put the file extension so I removed the .txt because when I kept it, it read it as "icecreamTopping.txt.txt"

Comment: In other words your filename was wrong in the directory and you renamed it. Nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 14):

Replace below line

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("icecreamTopping.txt"));
```

with

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("resources/icecreamTopping.txt"));
```

and put the file under resources folder that resides parallel to src folder.

---

Sample code:

Reading a file `abc.txt` from resources folder

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("resources/abc.txt"));
```

Here is the project structure

[image]

---

Try below code to find out where it is pointing to file `icecreamTopping.txt`.

```
 File f=new File("icecreamTopping.txt");
 System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

After getting the absolute path, just place the file there.

---

--EDIT--

As per your last comments, put `icecreamTopping.txt` file in the project `RankFavorites` directly as shown in below snapshot and It will definitely solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used the code to find where the file is being pointed and I got:C:\Users\homar_000\workspace\RankFavorites\icecreamTopping.txt
I tried putting it there, but it still didn't work. Even the RankFavorites/icecreamTopping.txt didn't work too. (I changed the \ to a / as well)

Answer (score -1):

Move the text file to java/main/resources folder if you are using Maven or to classes folder, so that it will be in classpath. Then use the following line of code to get the file path. Replace MyClass with your class name. Use the path as argument in FileReader.

String path = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("text_file.txt").getPath();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

Comment: You need to identify what the problem with the original code was, and there wasn't one. The question was self-answered eight years ago.

Comment: @user207421 There was a problem and that is why user posted this in stack overflow. User found the solution on his own later on. I faced a similar problem when I posted this solution which would help others facing similar problem. Solutions in stack overflow are not just for the user who asked the question but for the general audience, especially in this case when it has been solved many years ago.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use File class to detect your file in storage:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

Comment: That will *certainly* fail. It makes no sense whatsoever to delete a file you are about to try to read.

Answer (score -2):

```
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

try {
    
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/home/sahan/Desktop/data.json"));
    ObjectNode objNode = mapper.convertValue(obj, ObjectNode.class);
    System.out.println(objNode);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```