# how can I read from txt file into AVL tree in java? error FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, avl-tree, word-frequency

new java developer.
this code isn't working. it keeps generating this error: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: file1.txt (No such file or directory)` even though the file is in the same folder (src) as the java classes

my program is supposed to count the word frequency of words in a txt file. I'm trying to read through the txt file, and put each word into a node of an AVL tree, along with the frequency of the word in the txt file so each node would look like this: ("word", 5). this is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.io.IOException;



public class FindKeyWordsInFile {
    
    //public AVLTree.Node root;
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java FindKeyWordsInFile k file.txt MostFrequentEnglishWords.txt");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int k = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        String inputFileName = args[1];
        String englishWordsFileName = args[2];
        
        AVLTree<String, Integer> wordFrequencies = new AVLTree<>();
        AVLTree<String, Void> englishWords = new AVLTree<>();
        AVLTree<String, Integer> keywordFrequencies = new AVLTree<>();
        
        try {       
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
                for (String word : words) {
                    // Remove punctuation and convert to lower case
                    String cleanedWord = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").toLowerCase();
                    if (cleanedWord.length() > 0) {
                        Integer frequency = wordFrequencies.get(cleanedWord);
                        if (frequency == null) {
                            frequency = 0;
                        }
                        wordFrequencies.put(cleanedWord, frequency + 1);
                    }
                }
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
```

Comment: How do you run the program? Do you use a console command? Do you run it in an IDE?  Have you tried putting the file in the same subdirectory (folder) where the program is run?

Comment: I'm new here but this looks like it might help you out! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585621/the-filereader-cannot-find-my-text-file